# Java - How to fix InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm type - RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, key, java

I got a Private JKS file and a Password file for it. I saw the internet, wrote a java program which will print out the private key as a string.

Similarly I got a public key file with .cer extension. Similarly I printed out the contents of this file too as a string

My idea is to write a java program which has 2 methods encrypt and decrypt.I wrote all the stuff. But when I try to use my encrypt and decrypt function i am seeing InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm type. I printed out the algorithm from the jks file and I see it as RSA. In the public certificate the algorithm is printed as SHA1withRSA

here are my programs

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class ExtractKeys {

    private static String privateKeyalgorithm = "";
    private static String publicKeyAlgorithm = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String publicCertificate = "C:\\QA\\keys\\sis.cer";

        String privateKeyStore = "C:\\QA\\keys\\sis.jks";
        String privateKeyStorePassword = "sis";
        String alias = "sis";
        String aliasPassword = "sis";

        ExtractKeys myep = new ExtractKeys();

        myep.printPrivateKey(privateKeyStore, privateKeyStorePassword, alias, aliasPassword);
        myep.printPublicKey(publicCertificate);

    }

    public String printPublicKey(String source) throws Exception {
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        InputStream fis = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
        Base64 encoder = new Base64(64);

        fis = new FileInputStream(source);
        byte value[] = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(value);
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(value);
        java.security.cert.CertificateFactory cf = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bais);

        String cert_begin = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        String end_cert = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        publicKeyAlgorithm = cert.getSigAlgName();
        byte[] derCert = cert.getEncoded();
        String pemCertPre = new String(encoder.encode(derCert));
        String pemCert = cert_begin + pemCertPre + end_cert;
        System.out.println(pemCert);
        System.out.println(publicKeyAlgorithm);
        return pemCert;

    }

    public String printPrivateKey(String fileName, String keystorepass, String aliasName, String aliaspass) throws Exception {

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        Base64 encoder = new Base64(64);

        char[] keyStorePassPhrase = keystorepass.toCharArray();

        File certificateFile = new File(fileName);

        ks.load(new FileInputStream(certificateFile), keyStorePassPhrase);

        char[] aliasPassPhrase = aliaspass.toCharArray();

        KeyPair kp = getPrivateKey(ks, aliasName, aliasPassPhrase);

        PrivateKey privKey = kp.getPrivate();

        privateKeyalgorithm = privKey.getAlgorithm();

        String b64 = encoder.encodeAsString(privKey.getEncoded());

        System.out.println("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----");

        System.out.println(b64);

        System.out.println("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

        System.out.println(privateKeyalgorithm);

        return b64;

    }

    private KeyPair getPrivateKey(KeyStore keystore, String alias, char[] password) {

        try {

            // Get private key

            Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password);

            if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {

                // Get certificate of public key

                Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

                // Get public key

                PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

                // Return a key pair

                return new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);

            }

        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    public String returnPrivateKeyAlgo() {
        return privateKeyalgorithm;
    }

    public String returnPublicKeyAlgo() {
        return publicKeyAlgorithm;
    }
```

The outputs are strings of public key, private key, and their alogorithms

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCZehr60/61+4ao
8Bigkamzt3RJZcY9ggE4YuQ1ALY8pDXARDQ3OqPohySw4y+Ebrk4y/Rwzm21mhaU
jC33BNSNUetRAgBDU+/nT3/gRZdIeJRfFdiDtl/Ms2LYxo41nYTeGJEqoW3fivI2
cUG/tDKSPjaoGwnz/kVNIsZXJEcZCAfdIg1UH0wBeQ5qLR4rsseE0I7vVAfvDsMl
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
RSA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGiTCCBXGgAwIBAgIKYMbAHgAAAAUgKzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB5MRMwEQYK
CZImiZPyLGQBGRYDY29tMRYwFAYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYGc2Nod2FiMRYwFAYKCZIm
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
SHA1withRSA
```

Now I got the public and private keys as string values. along with their algorithms.

Next I wrote another sample program.I got 2 methods in it. encrypt and decrypt which also accepts these keys.

So ideally i would be passing the public key to encrypt method and the private key to decrypt method

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import **.CryptoService;
import **.CryptoServiceException;


public class CryptoServiceImpl implements CryptoService {

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, String key) throws Exception {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            Base64 decoder = new Base64(64);

            // decode the base64 encoded string
            byte[] decodedKey = decoder.decode(key);
            // rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
            final SecretKeySpec originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "RSA");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
            final String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(data));
            return encryptedString.getBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoServiceException("Cannot encrypt data using key '", e);
        }

    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, String key) throws Exception {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            Base64 decoder = new Base64(64);

            // decode the base64 encoded string
            byte[] decodedKey = decoder.decode(key);
            // rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
            final SecretKeySpec originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "RSA");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
            final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(new String(data))));
            return decryptedString.getBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoServiceException("Cannot decrypt data using key '", e);

        }
    }
}
```

Now I got a Junit which when executed throws this exception

```
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import **.CryptoServiceImpl;

public class TestCryptoService {

    String privateKeyStore = "C:\\QA\\keys\\sis.jks";
    String privateKeyStorePassword = "sistest";
    String alias = "sis";
    String aliasPassword = "sistest";
    static ExtractKeys myep = new ExtractKeys();
    CryptoService service = new CryptoServiceImpl();
    String publicCertificate = "C:\\QA\\keys\\sis.cer";;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

@Test
    public void testCryptoServiceForAESWithAsymmetricKeys() throws Exception {

        String publicKey = myep.printPublicKey(publicCertificate);

        byte[] encryptedValue = service.encrypt(new String("abcd").getBytes(), publicKey);
        System.out.println(new String(encryptedValue));

        String privateKey = myep.printPrivateKey(privateKeyStore, privateKeyStorePassword, alias, aliasPassword);
        byte[] decryptedValue = service.decrypt(encryptedValue, privateKey);

        System.out.println(new String(decryptedValue));
        Assert.assertEquals("abcd", new String(decryptedValue));
    }
}
```

and Here's the exception

```
*.CryptoServiceException: Cannot encrypt data using key '
    at *.impl.CryptoServiceImpl.encrypt(CryptoServiceImpl.java:59)
    at *.TestCryptoService.testCryptoServiceForAESWithAsymmetricKeys(TestCryptoService.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm type
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.RSAKeyFactory.engineTranslateKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.RSAKeyFactory.toRSAKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineGetKeySize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.b(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at *.impl.CryptoServiceImpl.encrypt(CryptoServiceImpl.java:55)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Mark line 59 in CryptoServiceImpl.java. It's a hassle for people to try to figure out where the exception originates.

Comment: @erickson the stacktrace shows it's in `Cipher.init` called from `CryptoServiceImpl.encrypt`; there's only one such call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate is not a public key although it contains one; more importantly, either a private key or public key or certificate for a public-key-crypto (aka asymmetric) scheme like RSA is not a symmetric key. Java `SecretKeySpec` is only for symmetric keys used with symmetric algorithms, like AES.

You need to represent your RSA keys using subtypes of `java.security.PrivateKey` and `java.security.PublicKey`. The way you do this is with a `KeyFactory` for RSA, or a `CertificateFactory` (as you already did).

For a PKCS#8-encoded private key, which is what you encoded and wrote out, decode it from PEM/base64 to `byte[]`, then:

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCSEncodedKeySpec (bytearray);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privkey = factory.generatePrivate (spec);
// use privkey in a Cipher.getInstance("RSA") to decrypt or sign
```

For a certificate do basically what you already did:

```
InputStream is = /* something that returns contents of cert file */;
// you *can* decode from PEM/base64 first, but you don't need to;
// CertificateFactory-X.509 handles both
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance ("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate (is);
// use cert.getPublicKey() for RSA encrypt or verify
```

Aside: sigAlgName for a certificate does NOT tell about the key *in* the cert. It is entirely possible for a cert signed SHA1withRSA to contain a DSA or ECC key that cannot be used for RSA, and conversely possible for a cert that contains a perfectly good RSA key to be signed with a different RSA variant (like SHA256withRSA) or an entirely different algorithm (like sha1-DSA or sha2-ECDSA).

Also note: you are explicitly importing `java.security.cert.Certificate`; that's good. JRE also has an older and deprecated `java.security.Certificate` which you should not use, but if you just say `Certificate` some IDEs (like mine) may get confused and give you the wrong one.